# gaussian integral solution..error in logic?

Tags: integration

Why oh why have I never seen anyone mention the apparent flaw in the logic of solving this integral by squaring it?? When you make the second integral integrable over y, yes y is just the name of the variable so it be du, dt, etc. anything BUT when you change to polar coordinates x and y have specific and DIFFERENT definitions.. x=rcos theta and y=rsin theta..Thus x and y do NOT euqal each other and therefore e^-x^2 times e^-y^2 is NOT the same as the square of e^-x^2..because when you square something it means you multiply it by ITSELF and sin theta does not always equal cos theta..Therefore the integral e^-x^2 dx does NOT equal the integral e^-y^2dy..only when theta equals 45 degrees or some multiple of it do the sin theta and cos theta terms equal and cancel each other and thus the x and y exponents would be equal and this would work..andOtherwise has no one ever aksed wy they cant solve it using e^-2rcos theta^2 ...by truly squaring the e^-x^2 integral..I don't see any flaw in my reasoning so can someone please explain if and why I am wrong..does it have to do with the power series expression for pi happening to work only for angles where cos theta and sin theta are equal or cancel each other?? Please someone answer Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Leif: [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for a guide to writing math with MathJax, and [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for a guide to formatting posts with Markdown.

Comment: Your question will be more readable if you break it up into paragraphs.

Comment: The main idea of the proof is geometric: we find the "volume" under the surface $z=e^{-(x^2+y^2)}$ and above the $x$-$y$ plane in two different ways, by rectangular coordinates integration and by polar coordinates integration.

Answer (score 4):

Answering by a finite analogy with integrals replaced by sums.

Surely you know that
$$
S=\sum_{n=1}^3n=1+2+3=6,
$$
and also that
$$\sum_{m=1}^3m=1+2+3=6=S.$$
Notice that there is no need to declare that $(m,n)$ should be on the
line with $\phi=\pi/4$. We never studied $m$ and $n$ together here.

It should not be a surprise that the double sum
$$
\sum_{n=1}^3\sum_{m=1}^3mn=36=\left(\sum_{n=1}^3n\right)\left(\sum_{m=1}^3m\right)=S^2.
$$
Let's check:
$$
\sum_{1\le m.n\le 3}mn=(1+2+3)+(2+4+6)+(3+6+9)=6+12+18=36=S^2.
$$
This was just the distributive law of multiplication and addition of integers at work.

Do notice that we can compute the last sum also by grouping together the terms, where $m+n$ is a constant:
$$
\sum_{1\le m,n\le 3}mn=(1)+(2+2)+(3+4+3)+(6+6)+(9)=36.
$$
Here the second group $2\cdot1+1\cdot2$, the third group $3\cdot1+2\cdot2+1\cdot3$ et cetera.

Basically that's what happening here. Except that in this case we were unable to calculate the value of $S$ directly, but we are able to calculate the value of $S^2$ after writing it as a double sum, and then regrouping according to the value of $x^2+y^2$. There are tons of technical details, because we are dealing with an integral: convergence, Jacobian, et cetera. But the basic idea is similar.

Answer (score 2):

Which of the following is equal to $\left[\int_a^b f(x)\,dx\right]^2,$
$$
\int_a^b\left[f(x)\right]^2\,dx\qquad\text{or}\qquad\int_a^bdx\int_a^bdy\,f(x)f(y)?
$$
If you answered the first one, then that is at the root of your difficulties in understanding the computation of $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\,dx.$  If that is indeed the problem, I would recommend trying some examples where you can compute all three integrals by hand, such as $f(x)=x^2$ with limits $a=0,$ $b=1.$

It should be said that your statement that $x\ne y$ is right, as is your statement that $e^{−x^2}\ne e^{−y^2}.$  In fact, how could they be equal in general?  Both $x$ and $y$ are variables, so they can take different values, which will generally not be the same.  When the integrals $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\,dx$ and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-y^2}\,dy$ are performed (taking a Riemann-sum point of view), $x$ and $y$ independently take on all the values between $-\infty$ and $\infty.$  While the variables and the integrands are not equal, the integrals are equal, since, as you pointed out, $x$ and $y$ are just different names for the integration variable.

It doesn't make sense to replace the variable $x$ in $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\,dx$ with $r\cos\theta.$  This replacement only makes sense in the context of the double integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\int_{-\infty}^\infty dy\, e^{-(x^2+y^2),}$ where $y$ would be replaced by $r\sin\theta$ at the same time.  Since the $x$-axis corresponds to $\theta=0,$ it would make sense to replace $x$ with $r\cos 0,$ but this just amounts to renaming $x$ to $r.$